# Patch a string with an unified diff in PHP

Tags: php, diff, patch

I am looking for a way to patch a string in PHP, using an existing unified diff. [xdiff_string_patch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-patch.php) does exactly what I want but the xdiff library is not available on my server.

Is there a way to do this in vanilla PHP or should I use something like *shell_exec('patch...')* ?

Regards,

Comment: Seems to me the only way to do it in "vanilla" PHP would be to write code that parses the diff & applies it (basically, rewriting `xdiff_string_patch` yourself). So `shell_exec` sounds like the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I ended up using:

```
/**
 * Applies a diff to a string
 * 
 * @param string $diff Diff
 * @param string $text String to patch
 * 
 * @return string Patched string
 * */
static function applyDiff($diff, $text)
{
    $tmpname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "diff");
    $outname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "diff");
    $tmp = fopen($tmpname, "w");
    $out = fopen($outname, "r");
    fwrite($tmp, $text.PHP_EOL);
    $proc = proc_open(
        'patch '.$tmpname.' -o '.$outname, array(
           0 => array("pipe", "r"),
           1 => array("pipe", "w"),
           2 => array("pipe", "w")
        ), $pipes
    );
    if (is_resource($proc)) {
        fwrite($pipes[0], $diff);
        fclose($pipes[0]);
        stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        $newText = stream_get_contents($out);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        return $newText;
    }
}
```